# If $B(V^{\tau_1},V^{\tau_2})\neq 0$ then $\tau_2$ is the dual representation of $\tau_1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $(\pi, V)$ be a representation of a finite group $G.$ Let $\hat{G}$ be a set of all irreducible representations of $G.$ Let $B$ be a non-degenerate $G$-invariant bilinear form on $V$. Suppose $V=\bigoplus_{\tau\in \hat{G}}V^\tau$ where $V^\tau$ is the sum of all $G$-invariant subspaces of $V$ isomorphic to $\tau$. Show that if $B(V^{\tau_1},V^{\tau_2})\neq 0$ for some $\tau_1,\tau_2\in\hat{G}$ then $\tau_2=\tau_1^\vee$ where $\tau_1^\vee$ is the dual representation of $\tau_1$.

---

We know that $\operatorname{Hom}_G(V,V^\vee)$ is isomorphic to the space $\operatorname{Bil}_G(V)$ of all $G$-invariant bilinear forms on $V$, as vector spaces. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The basic fact you need here is that if $V,W$ are $\mathsf k$-vector spaces then the space $\mathrm{Bil}(V,W)$ of bilinear maps $b\colon V\times W \to \mathsf k$ is isomorphic to the space $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathsf k}(V,W^{\vee})$.
The isomorphism is given as follows: if $b \in \mathrm{Bil}(V,W)$ then we obtain a map $v \mapsto \theta_v$ given by $\theta_v(w)=b(v,w)$ from $V$ to $W^\vee$, and similarly if we have a map $\theta \colon V \to W^{\vee}$ we
obtain a bilinear form $b_{\theta}$ given by $b_{\theta}(v,w) = \theta(v)(w)$.

These maps are readily checked to be inverses of each other and hence they are isomorphisms. The are also compatible with the action of $G$ if $V$ and $W$ are $G$-representations, and so in particular $\mathrm{Hom}_G(V,W)\cong \mathrm{Bil}_B(V,W)$.

Now a bilinear form $b\colon V \times V \to \mathsf k$ (where $\mathsf k$ is the field that $V$ is defined over) restricts to a bilinear form $b_{\tau_1,\tau_2}\colon V^{\tau_1}\times V^{\tau_2}\to \mathsf k$ (where $\mathsf k$ is the field that $V$ is defined over).

Thus if $B_{\tau_1,\tau_2}\neq 0$ then it gives a non-zero element in $\mathrm{Bil}_G(V^{\tau_1}, V^{\tau_2})$. Since $\mathrm{Bil}_G(V^{\tau_1},V^{\tau_2})\cong \mathrm{Hom}_G(V^{\tau_1},(V^{\tau_2})^\vee)$, we obtain a corresponding nonzero linear map $\theta_B\colon V^{\tau_1} \to (V^{\tau_2})^{\vee}$. Thus we may pick $S$ an irreducible subrepresentation of $V^{\tau_1}$ such that $\theta_B(S) \neq 0$. But then by definition of $V^{\tau_1}$, the isomorphism class $[S]$ of $S$ is $\tau_1$ and hence by the simplicity of $S$, since $\theta_B(S)$ is nonzero, it must be isomorphic to $S$. It follows that $(V^{\tau_2})^{\vee}$ contains a simple subrepresentation isomorphic to $\tau_1$. But by definition $(V^{\tau_2})^\vee$ has $\tau_2^{\vee}$ as its only composition factor, and hence it follows that $\tau_2 = \tau_1^{\vee}$.